# Can i add css property shortcuts to sublime text?

Tags: html, tags, sublimetext2

Can I add more shortcuts like this one to SublimeText?

Like one that is `"m-a"` that will expand to `margin: 0 auto;` ?

[image: Sublime Text 2 property shortcuts]

I apologize if this has already been asked. I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html). For this particular example, Open the `Tools` menu and select `New Snippet...`, then paste in the following:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[margin: 0 auto;]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>m-a</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.css</scope>
</snippet>
```

Save this file as `Packages/User/CSS/margin auto.sublime-snippet` and you should be good to go. Open a CSS file, type `m-a`, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and you're all set. Snippets are pretty powerful, and also allow for tab stops to enter customized data. For example, you could set up some boilerplate code that only requires that the colors be customized like so:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[body {
    max-width: 500px;
    _width: 500px;
    padding: 30px 20px 50px;
    border: 1px solid ${1:#b3b3b3};
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px ${2:#a7a7a7}, inset 0 1px 0 ${3:#fff};
    background: ${4:#fcfcfc};
}
$5
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>setbody</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.css</scope>
</snippet>
```

When you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to trigger the snippet, the `#b3b3b3` in the `border` property is highlighted, ready to be edited. When you're done, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to go to the first color definition in `box-shadow`, etc. The final <kbd>Tab</kbd> leaves you outside the brackets, ready for your next selector.